# dnsmasq - forwarding local dns queries

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I have two Openwrt APs with dnsmasq on each ap. Lets call them `DNS1` (main AP on 192.168.10.1) and `DNS2` (dumb AP on 192.168.10.2).  `DNS1` is also the only DHCP server on my local network.  I have stubby running on each instance to resolve external DNS requests on ports 5453.  I have a couple of static dhcp hosts on `DNS1` which I sync to `DNS2` and they resolve fine. My problem is, I cannot get `DNS2` to query `DNS1` if it cannot resolve a local (lan) query.  To clarify further: Since `DNS1` is also handles DHCP, a new client (`client1`) will only get resolved by `DNS1`.  Any client using `DNS2` as its dns server/resolver will not be able to resolve `client1` or `client1.lan`.  I thought adding a 'server=/lan/192.168.10.1' would do the trick, but no luck.  Here is my /etc/config/dhcp and autogenerated DNSMASQ.conf from DNS2:

```
config dnsmasq
    option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option localservice '1'
    option quietdhcp '1'
    option cachesize '4096'
    option readethers '1'
    option localise_queries '1'
    option expandhosts '1'
    option noresolv '1'
    option rebind_protection '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option filterwin2k '1'
    option domain 'lan'
    option domainneeded '1'
    list addnhosts '/adblock/custom'
    list addnhosts '/adblock/dlhosts'
    list addnhosts '/adblock/dlhosts-ipv6'
    option local_ttl '300'
    list server '/lan/192.168.10.1'
    list server '127.0.0.1#5453'
```

```
# auto-generated config file from /etc/config/dhcp
conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq.conf
domain-needed
filterwin2k
no-resolv
localise-queries
read-ethers
enable-ubus=dnsmasq
expand-hosts
bind-dynamic
local-service
quiet-dhcp
cache-size=4096
domain=lan
server=/lan/192.168.10.1
server=127.0.0.1#5453
addn-hosts=/tmp/hosts
addn-hosts=/adblock/custom
addn-hosts=/adblock/dlhosts
addn-hosts=/adblock/dlhosts-ipv6
dhcp-leasefile=/tmp/dhcp.leases
local-ttl=300
stop-dns-rebind
rebind-localhost-ok
dhcp-broadcast=tag:needs-broadcast
conf-dir=/tmp/dnsmasq.d
user=dnsmasq
group=dnsmasq
dhcp-ignore-names=tag:dhcp_bogus_hostname
bogus-priv
conf-file=/usr/share/dnsmasq/rfc6761.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely `dnsmasq`'s rebind protection kicking in from `stop-dns-rebind`. Check your logs, if you see lines like this then that is your issue.

```
dnsmasq[3835]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: hostname.lan
```

You want to add `rebind-domain-ok=lan` to your dnsmasq.conf. Your [OpenWRT config](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp) should look like this:

```
config dnsmasq
    list rebind_domain 'lan'
```